# How to define a relationship in laravel eloquent orm with custom name?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'm currently working on a laravel application where a user can like/dislike a content.
The migrations for the respective tables look as follows, where user_content_interaction is the relation between users and contents:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);


use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUserTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateContentTable extends Migration
{
    public const URL_LEN = 2083;
    public const STR_LEN = 256;
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('content', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title', self::STR_LEN);
            $table->date('release_date');
            $table->enum('content_type', ['movie', 'tv_show', 'short_film', 'mini_tv_show']);
            $table->json('genre');
            $table->json('tags');
            $table->integer('runtime');
            $table->longText('short_description');
            $table->json('cast');
            $table->json('directors');
            $table->enum('age_restriction', [0, 6, 12, 16, 18]);
            $table->string('poster_url', self::URL_LEN);
            $table->string('youtube_trailer_url', self::URL_LEN);
            $table->string('production_company', self::STR_LEN);
            $table->integer('seasons');
            $table->integer('average_episode_count');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('content');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUserContentInteractionTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_content_interaction', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('content_id')->constrained('content');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('user');

            $table->primary([
                'content_id',
                'user_id'
            ]);

            $table->enum('like_status', ['liked', 'disliked'])->nullable();
            $table->integer('dislike_count')->default(0)->nullable(false);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_content_interaction');
    }
}
```

The respective models look like this:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * Name of the associated Table in the Database
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'user';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function contents(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Content::class);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Content extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * Name of the associated Table in the Database
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'content';

    /**
     *
     * The primary key of the table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     *
     * The columns that are fillable
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'release_date',
        'content_type',
        'genre',
        'tags',
        'runtime',
        'short_description',
        'cast',
        'directors',
        'age_restriction',
        'poster_url',
        'youtube_trailer_url',
        'production_company',
        'seasons',
        'average_episode_count',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'varchar' => 'string',
        'release_date' => 'string',
        'content_type' => 'string',
        'genre' => 'string',
        'tags' => 'string',
        'runtime' => 'int',
        'short_description' => 'string',
        'cast' => 'string',
        'directors' => 'string',
        'age_restriction' => 'string',
        'seasons' => 'int',
        'average_episode_count' => 'int',
    ];
}
```

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class UserContentInteraction extends Pivot
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * Name of the associated Table in the Database
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'user_content_interaction';

    protected $primaryKey = 'content_id';

    protected $foreignKey = 'user_id';

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function content(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Content');
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to seed the database on my dev env like this:

```
        User::factory()->count(4)
            ->hasAttached(
                Content::factory()->count(10),
                [
                    'like_status' => Arr::random(['liked', 'disliked']),
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now()
                ],
            )
            ->create();
```

Which results in the following error when calling the create() method of the user factory:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::attach()`

I'm looking for any advice how to fix this problem, maybe I made a design mistake in the first place. Or there is an easier way to construct this relation. Though it would be cool if I could keep the custom name for the relation. I'm very unfamiliar with Eloquent ORM so when there is a much easier and lightweight way of doing this feel free to point that out.

EDIT:

I adjusted the relationship migration to look like this:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUserContentInteractionTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_content_interactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('user_content_interaction_id');
            $table->foreignId('content_id')->constrained('content');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('user');
            $table->enum('like_status', ['liked', 'disliked'])->nullable();
            $table->integer('dislike_count')->default(0)->nullable(false);
            $table->string('user_content_interaction_type');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_content_interaction');
    }
}
```

fixed some errors and defined the relation in the model like this:

```
    public function contents(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Content::class, 'user_content_interaction');
    }
```

Now I'm facing the problem that when seeding the ids from User and Content aren't taken into the relationship as foreign ids. The error message looks like this:

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `user_content_interactions` (`content_id`, `created_at`, `like_status`, `user_content_interaction_id`, `user_content_interaction_type`) values (1, 2022-10-26 16:51:14, disliked, 1, App\Models\User))
```

I think I have some mistake in the seeder. I feel like I have to do something like this in the seeder:

```
        User::factory()->count(4)
            ->hasAttached(
                Content::factory()->count(10),
                [
                    'user_id' => currentUser->id,
                    'content_id' => currentContent->id,
                    'like_status' => Arr::random(['liked', 'disliked']),
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now()
                ],
            )
            ->create();
```

Comment: You've defined `User::contents` as `hasMany`. That would be a 1:n relation. But you have n:n between users and contents.

Comment: Thanks for this it helped me, but now im facing another issue. I edited the question accordingly. Would be nice if you could have a look. @PaulSpiegel